# Use a variable when setting the getRange(value)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Is it possible to use a captured value inside a getRange(value) code?  If so, what do i need to change here?  It keeps failing on the last line of code and i have tried a few different options.

```
function test(row) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();// Define active sheet
  var amountdue = sheet.getRange("A30").getValue();// Capture amount due
  var rownumber = sheet.getRange("A30").getValue();// Capture row number
  sheet.getRange("B30").setValue(amountdue);// Paste amount due
  sheet.getRange("C"&rownumber).setValue(amountdue);// Paste amount due using captured row number
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that code:

```
function test(row) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();// Define active sheet
  var amountdue = sheet.getRange("A30").getValue();// Capture amount due
  var rownumber = sheet.getRange("A30").getRow()// Capture row number
  sheet.getRange("B30").setValue(amountdue);// Paste amount due
  sheet.getRange(rownumber,3).setValue(amountdue);// Paste amount due using captured row number
}
```

What I corrected:
when you are trying to get the row use the formula `getRow()`.
When you are trying to set the value to a cell with the retrieved row use the formula `getRange(`**`Integer row`**`,`**`Integer column`**`)` to point the good cell.